Rakshasas outside humans in Satyayuga but inside us in Kaliyuga -- In what texts is this idea found?
I found this interesting post on Quora:

First is Satya Yuga. The Rakshasas fought with Satya (not me!) being outside the Human race! But they cannot enter into the Human Race! [...]


Finally the Kaliyuga! The Rakshas entered each and every human and now we got both Satya (again not me) and Rakshas inside us! Daily each and Every moment the Satya and Rakshas are fighting inside us a Mahabaratha war and Rakshas wins sometimes and sometimes the Satya (not me) inside me wins!

Where does this come from? Anyone knows what Darshana/text(s) speaks about this?
